# match first character of every word

Tags: java, regex

Assuming all my words are seperated by blank spaces i.e sample sentence:

```
the browser keeps sending requests to check
```

I should match `tbksrtc`, which is first letter of every word. Is this better to do with regex? rather than spliting it into array(using blank space).

If yes, how would one write that regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=^|\s)\p{L}
```

which will match a letter if preceded either by whitespace or the start of the string. Don't forget to escape with abandon to actually force that regex into a Java string.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $s = 'the browser keeps sending requests to check'
PS> -join [regex]::Matches($s, '(?<=^|\s)\p{L}')
tbksrtc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match non-whitespaces:

```
String str = "the browser keeps sending requests to check";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S)(\\S+)").matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: `\w` will also match numbers, but not symbols -- important to keep in mind. A word like "don't" will throw it off.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this simple case, the more readable way is effectively to split the string:

```
public String generateInitials (String original){
    String[] words= original.split(" ");
    return retrieveInitialsOfEachWord(words);
}

private String retrieveInitialsOfEachWord(String[] words){
    String initials = "";
    for(String word : words){
        initials += word.substring(0,1);
    }
    return initials;
}
```

Indeed, it is more these few lines are far easier to understand than decoding a regexp and guessing the writer intents.

If developer doesn't well reveal his intention through the method name, it may be difficult to decode the regexp as expected.

Anyway, using basic java syntax or involving regexp with `Matcher` is just a matter of taste.